# Meaning of "I will not kill you due to your talent"

Tags: negation, attachment-ambiguity

What is the meaning of:

> I will not kill you due to your talent.

Does that mean:

1. [I will not kill you] [due to your talent].
   Because you are talented, I will not kill you.
2. [I will not] [kill you due to your talent].
   If I kill you, that's not because you are talented.

Comment: "Due" in these sentences just means "because of", so it depends on the context. As it is it's ambiguous.

Comment: It depends how you punctuate I think

Comment: #2 is technically feasible, but I think #1 is what most people would assume is being expressed.

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your option two; nor can I see any reasonable alternative way to interpret this example, no matter what punctuation is added.

Comment: @MikeB - I could see Option 2 being used in part of a longer sentence: _I won't do this because of XYZ, I'll do it because of ABC instead_.

Comment: @MikeBrockington The first interpretation means *I will not kill you, and I won't kill you because you're talented.* The second interpretation means *I **will** kill you, but it will be for some reason other than your talent.* While the second part of each interpretation is the same, whether or not the person is going to be killed at all is different. (In one scenario, the person dies; in the other, the person lives.) What makes it different in normal speech would be intonation and cadence—which is why punctuation is needed to clarify in written form.

Comment: I think there's another meaning - *Because you are talented, the thing I am about to do won't kill you*. I guess context is everything here